# Hangman program (python)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, hangman

I created a fairly simple hangman program as a little side project. Could you please tell me of any improvements/suggestions/criticism/feedback that you have about my code? Thank you in advance.

```
import tkinter as tk
import turtle
import string
from functools import partial
from draw_hangman import drawHangman
from random import randint

intro = tk.Tk()
intro.title('Menu')
intro_text = tk.Label(intro, text = 'Welcome to Hangman\nPlease choose your\ndifficulty rating:')
easy = tk.Button(intro, text = 'Hard (3-5 letters)', command = lambda: difficulty(3, 5))
medium = tk.Button(intro, text = 'Medium (5-10 letters)', command = lambda: difficulty(5, 10))
hard = tk.Button(intro, text = 'Easy (10-15 letters)', command = lambda: difficulty(10, 15))
intro_text.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
easy.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = 'news')
medium.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = 'news')
hard.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = 'news')


def enable():
    easy.config(state = 'normal')
    hard.config(state = 'normal')
    medium.config(state = 'normal')
    root.destroy()

def disableButtons():
    for w in root.winfo_children():
        if 'button' in str(w):
            w.configure(state="disabled")

def whenGuessed():
    win = ''
    global drawRate
    if entry.get().lower() == word:
        win = 'You win!'
        lab.config(text = word)
        disableButtons()
        t.clear()
    else:
        trash = draw[drawRate]
        exec(trash)
        drawRate+=1
        if drawRate > len(draw)-1:
            win = 'You lose!'
            lab.config(text = word)
            disableButtons()
            t.clear()
    if win != '':
        entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        entry.insert(0, win)

def whenPressed(button, text):
    global drawRate
    win = ''
    button.config(state = 'disabled')
    ind = []
    local_word = list(word)
    for i in local_word :
        if i == text:
            trash = local_word.index(i)
            ind.append(trash)
            local_word.pop(trash)
            local_word.insert(trash, '-')
    if len(ind) != 0:
        for i in ind:
            shown_text.pop(i)
            shown_text.insert(i, text)
        lab.config(text = ''.join(shown_text))
        for i in shown_text:
            if i == '-':
                trash = True
        if trash != True:
            win = 'You win!'
            disableButtons()
            t.clear()
    else:
        trash = draw[drawRate]
        exec(trash)
        drawRate+=1
        if drawRate > len(draw)-1:
            win = 'You lose!'
            lab.config(text = word)
            disableButtons()
            t.clear()
    if win != '':
        entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        entry.insert(0, win)
        
def difficulty(minimum, maximum):
    global word, lab, root, shown_text, drawRate, draw, t, entry
    file = open(r"C:\Users\d_j_d\Desktop\words.txt", 'r').read().split('\n')
    word = ''
    while len(word) < minimum or len(word) >= maximum:
        word = file[randint(0, len(file)-1)]
    shown_text = list('-'*len(word))
    draw = drawHangman()
    drawRate = 0
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Hangman 3.0')
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    easy.config(state = 'disabled')
    hard.config(state = 'disabled')
    medium.config(state = 'disabled')
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", enable)
    length = tk.Label(root, text = 'Length: '+str(len(word)))
    length.place(relx = 1, rely = 1)
    alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    lab = tk.Label(root, text = '-'*len(word), font = (None, 15), width = 30)
    lab.grid(row = 0, columnspan = 13, column  =  0)
    entry = tk.Entry(root)
    entry.grid(row = 3, columnspan = 10, sticky = 'news', column = 0)
    button = tk.Button(root, text = 'Enter', command = whenGuessed)
    button.grid(row = 3, columnspan = 3, sticky = 'news', column = 10) 
    for i in alphabet:
        btn = tk.Button(root, text=i)
        command = partial(whenPressed, btn, i)
        btn.config(command=command)
        row = (alphabet.index(i) // 13)+1
        column = alphabet.index(i) % 13
        btn.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="news")
```

`drawHangman` function:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
draw = [
    '''t.speed(10)
t.penup()
t.fd(200)
t.rt(90)
t.fd(200)
t.down()
t.lt(270)
t.fd(400)''',
    '''t.rt(90)
t.fd(400)''',
    '''t.rt(90)
t.fd(300)''',
    '''t.rt(90)
t.fd(75)
t.dot(75)''',
    't.fd(100)',
    '''t.lt(90)
t.fd(60)
t.back(120)
t.fd(60)
t.rt(90)''',
    '''t.fd(75)
t.lt(30)
t.fd(100)''',
    '''t.back(100)
t.rt(60)
t.fd(100)''']
def drawHangman():
    return draw
```